# Gnome Shell - Do not let windows float to first or accross workspaces

Tags: ubuntu, desktop, window-managers, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

Currently I use gnome-shell and put all windows I do not need right now on the second workspace. Two screens are attached to the computer.

For some reason the windows float back from the second to the first workspace after a while.
I believe that they come back if the main desktop is empty (first screen, first workspace is empty).

- Is there an option to prevent such behaviour?
- Can I force gnome-shell to keep everything where it is?
- (*optional*: Even if there is an whole empty workspace between)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with writing Gnome-Shell-Extensions. Also, if you don't want these "dynamic workspaces", you can disable them: http://www.maketecheasier.com/disable-automatic-workspaces-in-gnome-3/2011/07/14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

And in shell disable the "Dynamic Workspaces".

Thanks to Lukas Knuth!